# do not keep org-agenda-files open after generating agenda

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

Generating today's agenda in Org-Mode (`C-c a a`) opens the files in `org-agenda-files`.  I don't want Emacs to open these extra buffers.

Is there an easy way to tell Emacs not to open these buffers? (or what is the same, to automatically close them if they weren't open before calling the agenda?).

**UPDATE:**

This is a more compact version of the solution provided by @lawlist:

```
(require 'dash)

(defun my-org-keep-quiet (orig-fun &rest args)
  (let ((buffers-pre (-filter #'get-file-buffer (org-agenda-files))))
    (apply orig-fun args)
    (let* ((buffers-post (-filter #'get-file-buffer (org-agenda-files)))
           (buffers-new  (-difference buffers-post buffers-pre)))
      (mapcar (lambda (file) (kill-buffer (get-file-buffer file))) buffers-new))))

(advice-add 'org-agenda-list :around #'my-org-keep-quiet)
(advice-add 'org-search-view :around #'my-org-keep-quiet)
(advice-add 'org-tags-view   :around #'my-org-keep-quiet)
```

Regrettably, this still is not perfect, as now clicking on an event in the agenda does not open the corresponding org file.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You want `org-agenda-exit`, conveniently bound to x by default in the agenda view

> Like `org-agenda-Quit', but kill any buffers that were created by
>   the agenda.  Org buffers visited directly by the user will not be
>   touched.

I found this using `describe-mode`.

Comment: Sane answer here.

Comment: Appreciate the pointer to `describe-mode`.

Comment: `x` doesn't seem to work for the `Match a TAGS/PROP/TODO query` option.

Answer (score 4):

The `org-agenda-files` buffer(s) should *not* be killed until after the search functions have finished.  The three (3) most common search functions used to generate an `*Org Agenda*` buffer are:  `org-agenda-list`; `org-search-view`; and `org-tags-view`.  `org-agenda-files` is both a variable and a function -- two different, but related, animals.

```
(defvar opened-org-agenda-files nil)

(defun opened-org-agenda-files ()
  (let ((files (org-agenda-files)))
    (setq opened-org-agenda-files nil)
    (mapcar
      (lambda (x)
        (when (get-file-buffer x)
          (push x opened-org-agenda-files)))
      files)))

(defun kill-org-agenda-files ()
  (let ((files (org-agenda-files)))
    (mapcar
      (lambda (x)
        (when
            (and
              (get-file-buffer x)
              (not (member x opened-org-agenda-files)))
          (kill-buffer (get-file-buffer x))))
      files)))

(defadvice org-agenda-list (around opened-org-agenda-list-around activate)
  (opened-org-agenda-files)
  ad-do-it
  (kill-org-agenda-files))

(defadvice org-search-view (around org-search-view-around activate)
  (opened-org-agenda-files)
  ad-do-it
  (kill-org-agenda-files))

(defadvice org-tags-view (around org-tags-view-around activate)
  (opened-org-agenda-files)
  ad-do-it
  (kill-org-agenda-files))
```

Comment: That's good.  The only problem is that I wouldn't like to kill a buffer that was open before creating the agenda.  Thus, it seems that the right solution requires creating an "around" advice.

Comment: @scaramouche -- In my initial testing, the revised draft appears to do what it is that you are seeking -- it incorporates the `around` with `advice`.

Comment: Now there's another problem: pressing enter in an event in the agenda does not open the corresponding file.  Maybe there's no nice way of implementing this.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense (now that I think about it) because the `*Org-Agenda*` buffer is just a copy and paste from the `org-agenda-files` [kind of, it is actually pushed into a list and then reorganized and inserted into the `*Org-Agenda*` buffer].  When editing, a user jumps back to the original `org-agenda-files` to make the edit, which the editing functions assume is already open.  If you really have to have the `org-agenda-files` closed when not in use, then you'll need to revise the editing functions to open the file needed and then close it again when done.  There may also be other issues

Answer (score 2):

After you have opened the agenda, just exit it by pressing x in the agenda's buffer at any time. If you use q to quite the agenda it will keep all the buffers open.

Comment: Your answer is escentially a duplicate of `user2699` that was posted on February 19, 2016.